# What made my pancakes taste fizzy?

Tags: food-science, fruit

I made pancakes a couple times recently, and they had a strange reaction to some frozen raspberries we had. When we put the raspberries onto the pancakes, they had a strange fizzy and sour taste. We could still taste the sweetness of the pancake and toppings as well, but this fizz kept coming back. It was erratic, but probably due to not being evenly mixed.

The raspberries ingredient list just say that they're 100% raspberries. There were also blueberries from the same brand that didn't at all have this effect.

The pancakes contained:

- Flour
- Baking soda
- Salt
- Sugar
- Vanilla sugar
- Oil
- Soy milk

We used two different recipes but it happened both times. The second time we purposefully chose a recipe with less baking soda in case that mattered but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Also I live in Ireland if the locality affects how the frozen berries might be stored.

Comment: So... only the raspberries had that taste? And was it just a taste? The title makes it sound like the pancakes physically fizzed.

Comment: I also find this unclear. In addition to not knowing what you mean by "fizz", you say "a little sour and very acidic". This is impossible. Acidic is not a taste. Sour is the taste which you sense when you put something which has the chemical property of being acidic in your mouth. The difference is not that important in everyday life, so people will frequently say "it tastes acidic" when they mean "it tastes sour", but in this usage, it is impossible for something to be "a little sour" and "very acidic" at the same time.

Comment: @Jefromi I made some edits to try make it clearer. There wasn't physical fizzing, just a taste. I also removed the reference to acidic taste.

Comment: When I wrote my comment, my intention wasn't to point my finger at you and say "bad language, ha ha". If you describe something as "a little sour and very acidic", my guess is that you noticed two different tastes at once, but chose an unfortunate word for the second one. Can you find a better description for the second taste? It can be important. Also, are all recipes you tried free of acids? Could you have tasted the unreacted baking soda?

Comment: Do the berries taste fine if you eat them by themselves (outside of the pancakes)?  Did you see a "fizzy" reaction of any sort when you put the berries in, or is it only the taste affected?  Does any of the surrounding pancake batter taste "off," or is it only confined to the berries?

Comment: @rumtscho It was me and someone else both describing the taste, I said sour and they said acidic. In light of your comment I just folded the two into one because they couldn't think of any other way to say "acidic". There were no acids, just the ingredients listed above in both recipes. It may have been unreacted baking powder, I guess it could just be coincidence that it always occurred with raspberries?

Comment: @Athanasius The berries were fine otherwise. There was no visual reaction at all. And the pancake seemed fine when it wasn't in direct contact with the berries.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the taste is due to something like unreacted baking powder (which doesn't exactly taste "acidic") - the baking powder would clearly *react* with the acid in the raspberries, thereby *reducing* acidity.  At this point my only suggestion is that there was no reaction (since none was observed) and *for some reason* the flavors of the raspberries were just incompatible with this particular pancake batter. Just as a pairing with the right food can enhance the flavor of a good wine, so a bad pairing of ingredients can sometimes bring out or strengthen bad flavors.

Comment: @My initial guess was that he noticed two different tastes and had a hard time describing the second one, picking "acidic" where he meant something like "chemical". But after reading Jefromi's answer, this seems like a pretty good explanation. Superbiasedman, your baking soda still has little to nothing to react to. I would suggest that you try this recipe either with buttermilk instead of soy milk, or with baking powder instead of baking soda. It probably won't solve your taste problem, but it is likely to improve your texture.

Comment: Not that this is "scientific" evidence, but I happened to have some tasty fresh raspberries on hand last weekend, and I decided to throw them into some pancakes (which otherwise tasted delicious).  The raspberries in the pancakes tasted *horrible*, though -- for whatever reason, the sour notes were much stronger and almost bitter.  All who tried them unanimously agreed never to put raspberries in pancakes again.  I'm thus still convinced this is a recipe and flavor incompatibility problem, rather than due to some chemical reaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am willing to bet the high acidity of the berries reacted with the baking powder component of the pancakes.

Pancakes are just barely cooked batter and the carbonates are still pretty active, which is what makes good swiftly fried pancakes fluffy while pancakes cooked on too low a heat become rubbery and floppy.

It's also why if you replace fresh milk with fresh butter milk  (not buttermilk pancake mixes), it makes fabulous fluffy and tastier pancakes.

I am willing to bet your pancakes are pretty darn good aren't they?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! These were unusually good, fluffy batches, so you are probably correct. In future I'll save the raspberries for the rubbery pancakes.

Answer (score 1):

Raspberries are pretty sour, especially if underripe, so it could've just been that, if not for the fizzy taste.

That part makes it sound like the berries were a little fermented. That's unusual for frozen fruit, but possible if it wasn't stored right at some point along the line. If the fizzy taste was similar to too old orange juice or kim chee or anything else fermented you might've had, could well be it.

Comment: They only tasted fizzy when on the pancakes, when eaten by themselves or put on some brownies they tasted perfectly normal. Would fermented raspberries have reactions with food in the pancakes? Or were you suggesting they'd generally taste off?

Comment: This probably isn't it if they were fine on their own, unless maybe the contrast with the pancakes made you more sensitive to it.